# Can't figure out how to select movies categorized in specific genres

Tags: mysql, select

Tables' structure:

> Table MOVIES
>
> > mid title
> >     1 Oblivion
> >     2 Iron Man 3
> >     3 Cowboys & Aliens
>
> Table GENRES
>
> > gid genre
> >     1 Action
> >     2 Sci-Fi
> >     3 Western
> >     4 Drama
>
> Table MOVIEGENRES
>
> > mid gid
> >     1 1
> >     1 2
> >     1 4
> >     2 1
> >     2 2
> >     3 1
> >     3 2
> >     3 3

**Problem:**
Now I am trying to select only those movies which have both 'Western' and 'Sci-Fi' genres e.g. Cowboys & Aliens has both Western and Sci-Fi genre.

I have tried the following query but it returns all movies which have just any of the specified genres

```
SELECT m.title FROM movies m,moviegenres mg WHERE m.mid = mg.mid AND mg.gid in (2,3);
```

Comment: danihp, i have edited my question

Comment: how is the result? did you try the queries we provided?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this plays out as:

```
SELECT mid, COUNT(*) AS matches FROM moviegenres WHERE gid IN (4,5) HAVING matches=2
```

You'll adjust the `IN` contents to be N entries, and `matches=N`.

Comment: Change the values in the `IN` clause to whatever matches up with your data. This is just an example. By itself `IN` will match using *one or more* matches, but with the `HAVING` clause, you can restrict it to *N*, and if N is the maximum number, then it only matches those that match all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method see what came up.

> SELECT MOVIES.title FROM MOVIEGENRES AS a INNER JOIN GENRES as b ON a.mid
>   = b.mid INNER JOIN MOVIEGENRES as c ON a.gid =c.gid GROUP BY MOVIEGENRES.title

Comment: Btw, I hope the table are already have relationship between each other